# Calling window.open() multiple times fails after the first time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a script that loops through multiple urls and opens them in a new tab. It used to work but now only opens the first one. There's even a w3schools test editor that supposedly opens multiple windows, and it also fails after the first one:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open6

However, if I step through in debug mode and reset the focus to to original tab each time, it does open each window. So my question is, how do I open multiple windows(tabs) but keep the focus on my window with the original script? It used to do it that way, but now, as soon as a new tab is added, it gets the focus, and the script stops opening windows. Here's the full w3schools failing script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open multiple windows.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Windows</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com/");
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't omit the "window name" argument, use e.g. "_blank" as the name, or give an unique name for every window.

Comment: I believe chrome has a security feature which needs at least one user action per window.open, I might be wrong.

Comment: Firefox opened two windows for me; Chrome and Safari only opened the first one. Chrome additionally shows a "Popup blocked" message, allowing me to disable that security feature; @FZs is it possible you've already disabled it?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, I checked, and it is enabled. When I disabled them, only [Google](http://www.google.com) opened...

Comment: @FZs yeah, "Enabled" means you've enabled popups, i.e. disabled the security feature (of blocking popups). Weirdly confusing UI on Chrome's part, there....

Comment: Yes, Chrome had started blocking popups - a big duh for me not having checked that. Thanks for your help and time - I upvoted your comments.

Comment: @DanielBeck "Enabled"=enabled pop-ups

Answer (score 2):

As noted in another answer and the comments, it is a security feature.

It is worth adding, however, that you can disable it (on a per-site basis): simply click the small "popup blocker" icon at the right end of the address bar and enable popups from the current site.

Afterwards, feel free to shoot as many `window.open`'s as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think as @Daniel Sharp said, there is a security feature in chrome. It works fine in FF and IE.

**It works if I follow below steps:**

1. Click Open Windows (*A new window will open*)
2. Click on inital browser tab
3. Click somewhere on the page (*Except Open Windows button*)
4. Click on Open Windows again (*IT works this time - two windows are open*)

Answer (score 0):

The window name should be unique. Otherwise, the same page will refresh

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/","_google","height=200,width=150");
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/","_w3schools","height=200,width=150");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.